# Printing numbers , C++

Tags: c++

Hello I have written code and it looks like this (it tooks first number from a[], then second number from power of 2 and third  all even numbers):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int a[6] = { 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9 };
    int i = 0;
    int x;
    int even = 0;
    int sum;

    for (; a[i] < a[6]; i++)
    {
        for (int power = 1; power <= 64; power *= 2)
        {
            x = power % 10;
            for (int even = 0; even <= 6; even += 2)
            {
                sum = (a[i] + x + even);
                if (sum % 7 == 0)
                {
                    cout << a[i] << x << even << "  ";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I want it to print out  those numbers : `Out: 124 142 214 248 284 518 520 588 610 626 644 680 716 786 914 948 984`
But instead I get those: `124 142 160 124 142 214 284 266 520 520 610 626 644 680 662 626 644 716 786 914 984 966`

I don't know where's the problem,and numbers doubles couple of times. Please could somebody help me ?

Comment: What is the value of a[6]?

Comment: For me it shows  56 dont know why , but if I put a[5] instead it shows error "[Error] too many initializers for 'int [5]'"

Comment: The valid range of indices for your array is [0, 5].

Comment: So is there any way I can improve it ? Even though it shows me an error?

Comment: You seem to know what you should get and from this you should have a good expectetaion of what should happen on each line of code to give the expected output. Step through the program with whatever debugging utility came with your development environment. As you step, keep an eye out for where your expectations are violated. The unexpected is probably a bug. And when it isn't it means you're expectations are wrong and that is just as bad. Resolve the discrepancy before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

*You've wrongly accessed `a[6]`, which is an Undefined Behavior.*

the built-in subscript expressions work like this: If we perform `a[b]` on an array `a`, then it's equivalent to `*(a+b)`, while the first subobject of the array is stored in `a`(Here `a` refers to the *pointer prvalue* the array decaying to). Thus, to access the first element in an array, we use `a[0]`, i.e. `*a`

The number taking place in the declaration of an array is its size, formally speaking, the number of elements it can hold. Hence, if you do a simple math problem, the last valid subscript is `size - 1`, not `size`.

I think here you need to change

```cpp
for (; a[i] < a[6]; i++)
```

to

```cpp
for (; a[i] < a[5]; i++)
```

Comment: Ok ,I  got it and fixed it , but what about output  problem?

Comment: @Theooc What's your request? I don't know what do you want to do, so I can only fix a obvious error which can lead to unexpected results. Now that your code is normal, you need to provide more details if the results are still wrong.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks, I got it wrong. I' ll fix it immediately.

Comment: @drescherjm However, something fairly funny is that here if we presume the access won't crash, here if we could make use of the UB, maybe it'll work correctly, though it's a obvious error which must be corrected. Haha ;)

Comment: My idea  was to print first digit from vector a[] , then second digit -  power of 2  and the  third  number should be  even digits. sum of digits should be divisible by 7

Comment: @Theooc That's a math problem. The unit digit of `2^n` is not necessarily the power of 2. For example, `2^4 == 16`, but `6 == 2*3`